# Django rest framework: convert queryset to json response

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-serializer

I have two models, Appointment and EmployeeEvent. I need to get data from these models and combine the result in to a single get api request.

urls.py

```
url(r'^calenderevents', calender_events)
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def calender_events(request):
    queryset1 = Appointment.objects.all()
    queryset2 = EmployeeEvent.objects.all()
    return Response({'Appointments':json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', queryset1)), 'EmployeeEvents': json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', queryset2))})
```

When I call the API, I am getting the result, but it includes some unwanted keys like "pk", "model", "fields" etc. Also in the appoinments result, I need the full customer object instead of the customer id. Is there any way to specify the CustomerSerializer along with the query set?

Results am getting

```
{
  "Appointments": [
    {
      "pk": "33a0fffb-326e-4566-bfb4-b146a87a4f3f",
      "model": "appointment.appointment",
      "fields": {
        "customer": "25503315-8bac-4070-87c1-86bf0630c846",
        "status": "Requested",
        "description": "Assigned appointment",
      }
    },
    {
      "pk": "9da806f5-77f1-41e6-a745-7be3f79d6f7a",
      "model": "appointment.appointment",
      "fields": {
        "customer": "25503315-8bac-4070-87c1-86bf0630c846",
        "status": "Requested",
        "description": "Assigned appointment",
      }
    }
  ],
  "EmployeeEvents": [
    {
      "pk": "f76b5de0-1ab8-4ac3-947d-15ba8941d97d",
      "model": "employee_event.employeeevent",
      "fields": {
        "event_name": "New Event",

        "start_date": "2017-02-17",
        "end_date": "2017-02-22"
      }
    },
    {
      "pk": "56f02290-370e-426c-951e-a93c57fde681",
      "model": "employee_event.employeeevent",
      "fields": {
        "event_name": "New Event",
        "start_date": "2017-02-02",
        "end_date": "2017-03-22"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Result

```
{
  "Appointments": [
    {
      "id": "33a0fffb-326e-4566-bfb4-b146a87a4f3f",
      "customer": {
        "id": "25503315-8bac-4070-87c1-86bf0630c846",
        "firstname": "Customre 1",
        "photo_url": "imagepath",
      },
       "status": "Requested",
       "description": "Assigned appointment"
    },
    {
      "id": "9da806f5-77f1-41e6-a745-7be3f79d6f7a",
      "customer": {
        "id": "15ba8941d97d-8bac-4070-87c1-86bf0630c846",
        "firstname": "Customre 2",
        "photo_url": "imagepath",
      },
       "status": "Requested",
       "description": "Assigned appointment"
    },
    }
  ],
  "EmployeeEvents": [
    {
      "id": "f76b5de0-1ab8-4ac3-947d-15ba8941d97d",
      "event_name": "New Event 1",
      "start_date": "2017-02-17",
      "end_date": "2017-02-22"
    },
    {
      "id": "56f02290-370e-426c-951e-a93c57fde681",
      "event_name": "New Event 2”,
      "start_date": "2017-02-17",
      "end_date": "2017-02-22"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: please read rest framework tutorial, http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

Comment: @aliva, what a great answer!!!

Answer (score 16):

You need to write a serializer to display the data in the desired format. Read the excellent tutorial to guide you though it properly. But if you want a quick hacky answer, then do something like this:

```
serializer = AppointmentSerializer(Appointment.objects.all(), many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Where the serializer looks something like this:

```
class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = CustomerSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('id', 'customer', 'status', 'etc...')
        related_object = 'customer'

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'etc...')
```

Edit: updated to include example of a related object